# Restriction in rails got error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I want to do:

If seller.accounting_acc then 'all state are possible', If seller doesn't have account_access then 'All state except sale/in-hand'

Here's my code:

```
<% if current_user.seller? && current_user.accounting_access? %>
  <%= select_tag :set_state, options_for_select(state_options_for_seller, "comment"), class: "form-control set_state", id: "prospect_form_set_state" %>
<% else %>
  <%= select_tag :set_state, options_for_select(state_options_for_seller, "comment", disabled: "sale"), id: "prospect_form_set_state" %>
<% end %>
```

I am stuck in this issue.

Comment: This should be handled by the `state_options_for_seller` method. You should pass the current_user and do all the conditionals in the method. Only return the options that are available for the user. This would clean up your view as well.

Comment: @bo-oz , can i just disabled in the view ?

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<%= select_tag :set_state, options_for_select(state_options_for_seller(current_user), "comment"), class: "form-control set_state", id: "prospect_form_set_state" %>
```

Method (in the state model?), meta code, don't know the exact field names of course, so please adapt to your situation.

```
def state_options_for_seller(current_user)
  if current_user.seller? && current_user.accounting_access?
    return State.all
  else
    return State.where.not(state: 'sale')
  end
end
```